# In firefox while fetching the data for CORS We can use only jsonp or script but if cant get data then it shows syntax error

Tags: php, jquery, jsonp, cors

**php code**

```
<?php
$data = trim(api_get('threads',array(),'JSON'));
echo $_GET['jsonp_callback'] . '(' . $data . ');';
?>
```

**js code**

```
<script>
$.ajax({
              url: "https://abc.secure.tttt.com/",
              data:{},
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              cache: false,
              crossDomain: true,
              jsonp : "jsonp_callback",
              success: function(params){
                    console.log('showInbox');
                    //console.log(JSON.parse(params));
                    showInbox(params);
              },
              error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                console.log('Inside showInbox ajax failure');
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr));
                console.log(thrownError);
              }


});
```

this is working fine, if the API is giving json data and if there an error, it is showing syntax error:

```
Timestamp: 5/9/2013 4:28:24 PM
Error: SyntaxError: syntax error
Source File: https://abc.secure.tttt.com/?jsonp_callback=jsonp1368095332316&_=1368097103961
Line: 1
Source Code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Your JSONP feed starts with `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Comment: Yes the problem is if I'm logged out from my current page and if API is not returning anything then jsonp_callback causes a problem. It adds in url + the html of the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Use timeout property to get error function executed on error.

```
$.ajax({
              timeout : 2000,
              url: "https://abc.secure.tttt.com/",
              data:{},
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              cache: false,
              crossDomain: true,
              jsonp : "jsonp_callback",
              success: function(params){
                    console.log('showInbox');
                    //console.log(JSON.parse(params));
                    showInbox(params);
              },
              error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                console.log('Inside showInbox ajax failure');
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr));
                console.log(thrownError);
              }


});
```

In most browsers there is no way of telling if the JSONP request succeeded, other than a timeout. Of course set it to a reasonable value, I use 2 seconds guessing if the server doesn't return the file in this time, something is wrong.

Comment: No this is not helping me out...
The actual problem is if I'm logged out from my current page and if API is not returning anything then jsonp_callback causes a problem. It adds in url + the html of the login page. Which causes the problem and showing the Syntax Error.

Comment: Does the syntax error stop execution of your script containing $.ajax request? When I tested similar code myself, FireBug and such showed syntax error from loaded json file, but it didn't stop the script which requested it. The only way to detect such syntax error and react to it is to set a timeout. Another cause of syntax errors in jsonp replies is when you try to read the same file again BEFORE first request was completed, aborted or timed out.